# Update div using ajax.beginform inside asp mvc view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I want to show a success message after calling the following ajax.beginform
from Index view

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Insert", "Home", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "result", HttpMethod = "POST" }))
{
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.openion)
}
```

this is my result div

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

and my controller is

```
[Httppost]
public ActionResult InforMessage(openionModel usr)
    {
        return Content("Thanks for adding your openion");
    }
```

but when i try this it is going to another view InforMessage
It is not updating the result div.
There is no Informessage Exist. Still it open a new page with message
"Thanks for adding your openion".How to solve this?

Comment: Then you have not included the relevant scripts - `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: please let me know where i have to include. i am new to all these

Comment: Does you view have `@section Scripts {` section? If so in there. Otherwise just include in immediately before the closing `</body>` tag. And you also need `jquery{version}.js` which needs to be before `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js`

Comment: <script src="~/myScripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>


<script src="~/myScripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script> I have added this .. but still not getting.these scripts are there in the specified folder. But after adding this it is not going to other page just staying in the same page. action result is calling when i debugged using break point

Comment: user ``@Url.Content()`` for the urls of css and js files

Comment: @Stephen Muecke 29   After adding that js it worked perfectly. If you put it in the Answer question part, I can add it as my answer.That can help other begginers like me to look into it .Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your redirecting to another page its because you do not have the correct scripts loaded (or have duplicates or have them in the wrong order) so its doing a normal submit.

Ensure you have included (in order)

```
jquery-{version}.js
jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
```